# laravel Update and read on same page

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am currently making a admin dashboard to view the users. i want to make a Full crud on 1 page, i have the C, R, D part of it already finished and working. now i want to add a Update function. but this does not work, whatever i try.

Main page:

```
@include('admin.user.create')

  
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1 class="display-3">Users</h1>
      
    @if(session()->get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session()->get('success') }}  
    </div>
  @endif
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>picture</td>
          <td>company</td>
          <td>username</td>
          <td>email</td>
          <td>role_id</td>
          <td colspan = 2>Actions</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->name}} </td>
            <td><img src="/image/{{$user->picture}}" width="100px"/> </td>
            <td>{{$user->company}} </td>
            <td>{{$user->username}} </td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->role_id}} </td>

            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.user.edit',$user->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('admin.user.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="post">
                  @csrf
                  @method('DELETE')
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
<div>
</div>
@include('admin.user.edit')
```

it does include the code of admin.user.edit, but when i click on the edit button in the Read table i just keep getting errors.

controller:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

         return view('admin.user.index', compact('users'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
    
        
    }

  
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'picture'=> '',
        'company'=> '',
        'username'=> '',
        'email'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required',
        'role_id'=> 'required',
       ]);

       $user = new User([
        'name'=> $request->get('name'),
        'picture'=> $request->get('picture'),
        'company'=> $request->get('company'),
        'username'=> $request->get('username'),
        'email'=> $request->get('email'),
        'password'=> $request->get('password'),
        'role_id'=> $request->get('role_id'),
       ]);
       $user->save();
       return redirect('admin/user');
    }

   
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

 
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        return view('admin.user.index', compact('users'));

        
    }
```

Edit page i include in the main page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <h1 class="display-3">Editing user</h1>
 
        @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br /> 
        @endif
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.user.update', $user->id) }}">
            @method('PATCH') 
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
 
                <label for="name"> Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $user->name }}" />
            </div>
 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">email </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}" />
            </div>
 
           
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "_i just keep getting errors_" What would those errors be?

Comment: Where is the route file? and where is your code for update method?

Comment: the error i get with the current code is: Attempt to read property "id" on bool

Comment: What line? Which part of your code? (Basically, what you think is an object is a boolean)

Comment: Please share your route file here

Comment: Unrelated fyi: the `width` attribute doesn't take a unit, it's an integer

Comment: @NimaPatel  Route::resource('/user', App\Http\Controllers\admin\UserController::class); do you mean this?

Comment: @brombeer on this line:     <td>{{$user->id}}</td>

Comment: `$users = User::find($id);` ... `User::find(...)` returns _one_ user, that variable "should" be named `$user`. You also seem to refer to `$user` in your view but are passing `$users` to it

Answer (score 2):

Ohh I got your problem please check your mistake you used $user instead of $users  in blade file for  example

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.user.update', $user->id) }}">
```

you pass "users" in your controller and used $user in blade file

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $users = User::find($id);
    return view('admin.user.index', compact('users')); 
}
```

for single record please use to prefer $user in both controller and blade file

Comment: this give the following error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Did this solve your problem @Delanovanlonden ?

Comment: Did you change $user to $users in your blade file? or for single record please use to prefer $user in both controller and blade file

Comment: this did not work, but in my edit function i gave back 2 variables , this worked for me. but i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

i made 2 vars instead of giving 1 back in the edit function. this worked for me since i did not overwrite users

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).